# Inserter & Extractor function in C++

Tags: c++, inputstream, outputstream

q1.

> All inserter functions have this general form:

```
  ostream &operator<<(ostream &stream,class_type obj){
 //body of inserter 
    return stream; 
}
```

The first parameter to the function is a reference to the output stream. So,my question is Can i make that parameter an object of ostream i.e

Is this definition valid?

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream stream,class_type obj)  //Can i create a parameter of stream object here
```

**How can i make the parameter a stream object rather than a reference to a stream?**

q2.
Can you please explain why insertors and extractors are required to return a ref to a stream. (An example would be very helpful!)

Thanks!

Comment: why do you want to do this?

Comment: @tobi303 just out of curiosity

Answer (score 4):

1: No, you can't make it an object (i.e. passed by *value*) as the operator needs to act on the original stream. If you pass the object in, it will create a copy, act on that and then discard it at the end of the function.

2: They need to return a reference to a stream (not just any stream, but the same stream that was passed as a parameter) in order to enable this:

```
cout << "Multiple " << "outputs";
```

If you didn't return the reference, the next `<<` operator in the chain wouldn't also be able to act on the same stream as you wouldn't have returned it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do whatever you like: take a stream by value, take something else than a stream, return by copy, don't return anything, or return any kind of object you like. But... you won't get the behavior you expect for working with streams.

The correct way of looking to this is: first know what syntax you are trying to enable and what its behavior should be and then understand why things have to be done in a certain way in order for that syntax to work that way.

So. What you are trying to enable is this. Let's say you have a custom class `X` and you decide to make it to work with output stream. This means you want the following to work:

```
cout << x;
cout << x << x;
cout << x << " test ";
cout << " test " << x << " test ";
// etc
```

For all of those to work as intended you need to have `operator<<` take a `std::ostream` by reference and return a reference to the same ostream object.